# Cocos2D - Adding holes and different heights between buildings

Tags: path, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to build something similar to Canabalt, adding holes and different heights between buildings (modules). You can see a screenshot of how the game is looking right now at: http://twitpic.com/4kb5jd

Here is the code I'm currently using:

```
-(id) init
{
    // always call "super" init
    // Apple recommends to re-assign "self" with the "super" return value
    if( (self=[super init] )) {

        moduleSize = 160;

        screenSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

        CCSpriteFrameCache* frameCache = [CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache];
        [frameCache addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"ModulesScene1.plist"];

        CCTexture2D* gameArtTexture = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"ModulesScene1.png"];

        // Create the background spritebatch
        spriteBatch = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithTexture:gameArtTexture];
        [self addChild:spriteBatch];

        numStripes = 1;

        /* BEGIN MODULES */

        NSString* frameName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Module0-hd.png"];
        CCSprite* sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:frameName];
        sprite.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5f);
        sprite.position = CGPointMake(0, screenSize.height / 2);
        [spriteBatch addChild:sprite z:0 tag:0];

        frameName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Module0-hd.png"];
        sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:frameName];
        sprite.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5f);
        sprite.position = CGPointMake((moduleSize - 1.1f), screenSize.height / 2);
        [spriteBatch addChild:sprite z:1 tag:1];

        frameName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Module1-hd.png"];
        sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:frameName];
        sprite.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5f);
        sprite.position = CGPointMake((moduleSize * 2) - 1.1f, screenSize.height / 2);
        [spriteBatch addChild:sprite z:2 tag:2];

        frameName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Module2-hd.png"];
        sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:frameName];
        sprite.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5f);
        sprite.position = CGPointMake(((moduleSize * 3) - 1.1f), screenSize.height / 2);
        [spriteBatch addChild:sprite z:3 tag:3];

        frameName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Module0-hd.png"];
        sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:frameName];
        sprite.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5f);
        sprite.position = CGPointMake(((moduleSize * 4) - 1.1f), screenSize.height / 2);
        [spriteBatch addChild:sprite z:4 tag:4];

        frameName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Module1-hd.png"];
        sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:frameName];
        sprite.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5f);
        sprite.position = CGPointMake(((moduleSize * 5) - 1.1f), screenSize.height / 2);
        [spriteBatch addChild:sprite z:5 tag:5];

        /* END MODULES */

        // Get current scrollSpped
        scrollSpeed = [[GameManager sharedGameManager] scrollSpeed];

        speedFactors = [[CCArray alloc] initWithCapacity:numStripes];
        [speedFactors addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.5f]];
        NSAssert([speedFactors count] == numStripes, @"speedFactors count does not match numStripes!");

        [self scheduleUpdate];

    }

    return self;

}

-(void) update:(ccTime)delta
{

    CCSprite* sprite;
    scrollSpeed = [[GameManager sharedGameManager] scrollSpeed];

    CCARRAY_FOREACH([spriteBatch children], sprite)
    {

        NSNumber* factor = [speedFactors objectAtIndex:0];

        CGPoint pos = sprite.position;
        pos.x -= scrollSpeed * [factor floatValue];

        if (pos.x < -screenSize.width)
        {

            pos.x += ((screenSize.width * 2) - 2);

            int x = (arc4random() % 3);

            int xHole = (arc4random() % 10);

            NSString *randomName = nil;

            CCSpriteFrame *randomFrame = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:randomName];
            [sprite setDisplayFrame:randomFrame];

        }

        sprite.position = pos;

    }

}
```

Comment: Right now all buildings are all at the same height and attached to one another. I'd like them to randomly be slightly higher or lower and add space between them as if there was a hole.

Answer (score 0):

to add holes between the buildings you could add a simple rand() function like that in the **init** method:

...

```
sprite.position = CGPointMake(((moduleSize * 3) - 1.1f + (rand()%40)), screenSize.height / 2);
```

...

this will add a random gap (max 40 points)